# How to include a \newcommand in \maketitle

Tags: titles, signatures

This is my first time using LaTeX and I really need help. I am making my College Seminar report.

I am unable to make the newcommand `\namesig` appear on the title page.

[image]

Here is the `.tex` code

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin=4.5cm,
vmargin=4.5cm]{geometry} 
%%Name of the Title and subtitle
\title{%
  The uIP Stack \\
  \large A Small Memory Footprint TCP/IP Stack for Microcontrollers\\
  } 
%% First Page of the Report
\author{Mohammad Arshad Ali \\ 
{ECE-A}\\
{B.E. 4/4}\\
{2451-15-735-040}\\
}
%% Signature of the Guide
\newcommand{\namesig}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
    #2 \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[0pt]
    {\small \textit{Signature}} 
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent \namesig{Dr. K. Usha}\hfill \namesig{Sudhir Dakey}
\end{document}
```

I know that there are many previous posts quite similar to this, but I am unable combine to the source codes properly.

Also please suggest me, where can I find source codes particular to my requirement i.e., a documentation or text book where I can find the source codes with a little explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just redefine `\maketitle` to do what you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin=4.5cm,
vmargin=4.5cm]{geometry} 
%%Name of the Title and subtitle
\title{%
    The uIP Stack \\
    \large A Small Memory Footprint TCP/IP Stack for Microcontrollers\\
} 
%% First Page of the Report
\author{Mohammad Arshad Ali \\ 
    {ECE-A}\\
    {B.E. 4/4}\\
    {2451-15-735-040}
}
%% Signature of the Guide
\newcommand{\namesig}[2][5cm]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
        #2 \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[0pt]
        {\small \textit{Signature}} 
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}

        \pagestyle{empty}
        \phantom{.}  %necessary to add space on top before the title
        \vspace{3cm}

        {\Huge \bf \@title\par}
        \vspace{2.5cm}

        {\LARGE \@author}\\[1cm]

        {\Large\@date}

        \vspace{4.5cm}
    \noindent \namesig{Dr. K. Usha}\hfill \namesig{Sudhir Dakey}
        %if you want something in the bottom of the page just use /vfill before that.

    \end{center}
}\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you suggest me an easy to use online resource or text book to use LaTex? How did you start learning?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the `titlepage` enironment you can achieve something like this. You can of course adjust font sizes, alignments and distances to your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin=4.5cm,vmargin=4.5cm]{geometry} 

\newcommand{\namesig}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
    #2 \\[2\normalbaselineskip] \hrule \\[0pt]
    {\small \textit{Signature}} 
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{2cm}
\LARGE The uIP Stack 

\large A Small Memory Footprint TCP/IP Stack for Microcontrollers
\vspace{2cm}

Mohammad Arshad Ali \\ 
{ECE-A}\\
{B.E. 4/4}\\
{2451-15-735-040}\\
\vspace{1cm}

\today

\vspace{5cm}

\namesig{Dr. K. Usha}\hfill \namesig{Sudhir Dakey}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Leandriis. Also, can you suggest me a good textbook or document or a website where I can find basic source codes. So that next time when I ask questions they will be more thoughtful.

Comment: @MdArshadAli: I an nor sure whay you mean by 'basic source code'. However, maybe you are interested in :[What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/134144)